# Probability- Why is this approach wrong?

Tags: probability

> In a Math paper there are 3 sections A,B&C. Section A is compulsory. Passing in the paper means passing in A & passing in B or C. The probability of the student passing in A,B & C are $ P(A),P(B)$ and $P(C)$ respectively. What is the probability that the student is successful ?

**Approach 1**

$P(Success) = P(A∩\bar B∩C) + P(A∩B∩\bar C) + P(A∩B∩C)$

In this approach I'm trying to find the probability by considering possible cases in which the student can pass the exam.

**Approach 2**

$P(Success) = P(A∩(B∪C)) = P((A∩B)∪(A∩C)) = P(A∩B) + P(A∩C) $

$P(Success) = P(A∩B∩\bar C) + P(A∩B∩C) +P(A∩B∩C) + P(A∩\bar B∩C)$
$P(Success) = P(A∩B∩\bar C) + 2P(A∩B∩C) + P(A∩\bar B∩C)$

In the second approach I am converting the question into the asked probability notations.
The answer from which approach is right. Why is this so?

Comment: I am having difficulty following what it is you think you are saying, but $\Pr((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C))$ is not equal to $\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(A\cap C)$.  Instead it is equal to $\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(A\cap C)\color{red}{-\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)}$.  See [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: As for why $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A\cap B\cap \overline{C})+\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$, that is merely the [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: @JMoravitz aren't A, B and C mutually exclusive ?   $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A\cap B\cap \overline{C})+\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$ ' cause they are independent of each other.

Comment: Did you mean to say "Approach 1 is right"? Because Approach 2 is wrong.

Comment: "Mutually exclusive" means $P(X \cap Y)=0$, so the answer would be zero. "Independent" means $P(X \cap Y) = P(X)P(Y)$ - that's multiplication, not addition.

Comment: Note if the second answer is right, then for a good student who is likely to pass all three sections: $P(A \cap B \cap C) > \frac{1}{2}$, the probability of passing is larger than 1!

Comment: @Adidas10 $A,B,C$ are not necessarily mutually exclusive here.  They might not be independent either.  It is perfectly reasonable for events to neither be mutually exclusive nor independent.

Comment: @Rivers McForge I wanted to ask which one is correct ?( I Apologize for mistake)

Comment: @aschepler mutually exclusive *implies* that $\Pr(X\cap Y)=0$ but that is not the definition of mutual exclusivity.  Mutually exclusive means that $X\cap Y=\emptyset$.  It is possible for two events to not be mutually exclusive yet still have $\Pr(X\cap Y)=0$, for example with continuous distributions and infinite sample spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with Approach 2 is that it double counts $P(A \cap B \cap C)$. You can even see this in the last of your equations, which has a superfluous factor of $2$ on $P(A \cap B \cap C)$:

> $P(Success) = P(A∩B∩\bar C) + 2P(A∩B∩C) + P(A∩\bar B∩C)$

To understand what went wrong in approach 2, let's call event $E := A \cap B$, event $F := A \cap C$, so that $E \cap F = A \cap B \cap C$. Then when you write down

> $P(Success) = P(A∩(B∪C)) = P((A∩B)∪(A∩C)) = P(A∩B) + P(A∩C)$

this is equivalent to saying $$P(\text{Success}) = P(E \cup F) = P(E) + P(F),$$ which is only true when $E, F$ are disjoint. What it should really be is $$P(\text{Success}) = P(E \cup F) = P(E) + P(F) - P(E \cap F),$$ and the subtracted probability is exactly the double-counted $P(A \cap B \cap C)$.

Comment: aren't A, B and C mutually exclusive ?

Comment: @Adidas10 It doesn't sound like it from your problem statement. If they were mutually exclusive then everyone would fail, because passing $A$ would mean failing $B$ and $C$, but you need to pass $A$ and at least one of $B$ and $C$ to pass overall.

Comment: Ah! Got it Sir, Thanks.